# Reverse Relational Lookup on Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, relationship

I'm using [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational) to manage my models, and I came to a problem that I couldn't find a `good` solution.

Let's say that I have to models:

`Team: name, number, country`

`Member: name, Team (Pointer to Team)`

I want to fetch ALL Teams, and include all it's Members in one single query. If this is not possible, I will have to run a query for every Team that I fetches.

Is it possible with Parse? I read their docs. but couldn't find a way to doit...

Answer (score 3):

If the point is to get all of both members and teams, why not get all members and use

```
includeKey("Team")
```

to include all team objects in the members query?

On another note, when designing for parse (or any other NoSQL database), you should start with defining what queries you will make and then design your "schema".

Since you have a pointer to Team from Member, it seems that this is a one-to-many relationship. A team can have many members, but a member can only belong to one team.

So, what queries will you mostly perform?
Never "list all Teams a Member belongs to", because it can only be one.
You will query for members, and it would probably be nice to see the Team as well.
You will (apparently) query for Team(s) and need to get all members for that team.
Other queries related to Team or Member?

If you need a list of members in a Team, you could make "Members" a PFRelation from Team to Member. I know this seems odd if you're used to SQL databases, but that is not unusual in NoSQL databases.

Comment: The thing is that there will be 700 Members for 20 Teams. Getting 700 Members with it's Teams means: 700 teams + 700 members; Getting 20 Teams with it's mebers = 20 Teams + 700 members; Instead of 1400 objects, would be +-730

Comment: True, hence my suggestion to rethink the schema based on what queries you will perform.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the link in your post, my best guess is this:

```
var Member = Parse.Object.extend("Member");
var query = new Parse.Query(Member);

// Include the Team data with each Member
query.include("post");

query.find({
  success: function(members) {
    for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
      // This does not require a network access.
      var team = comments[i].get("team");
    }
  }
});
```

The above (untested) sample is modified from the section on `include`.

You may not be able to do what you want here, depending on the size of your `members` list and `team` list... I ran across this in the docs:

> If you want to retrieve objects where a field contains a Parse.Object
>   that matches a different query, you can use matchesQuery. Note that
>   the default limit of 100 and maximum limit of 1000 apply to the inner
>   query as well, so with large data sets you may need to construct
>   queries carefully to get the desired behavior. In order to find
>   comments for posts containing images, you can do:

Comment: I had to fetch them separately, and then associate in-code... Thanks for the answer!